EF core 8 specify one to many navigation property using Attributes
I'm getting the following error:
The exception 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Stock.StockTransactions'
I have these two classes:
public class Stock
{
    public int StockId { get; set; }

...
    
    public virtual List<StockTransaction> StockTransactions { get; set; } = new();

}


public class StockTransaction
{
    public int StockTransactionId { get; set; }

....

     public int StockId { get; set; }
     public virtual Stock Stock {get;set;}

     public int? StockFromId { get; set; }
     public virtual Stock? StockFrom { get; set; }

     public int? StockToId { get; set; }
     public virtual Stock? StockTo { get; set; }

}

I'm guessing it's having issues as there is multiple Stock navigation properties (Due to stock being able to be transferred between stock rows, and needing to keep a record of where that stock originated from)
How can I specify (using attributes preferably) that Stock.StockTransactions navigation property relates to StockTransactions.StockId

Have you tried this:
public class Stock
{
    public int StockId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Stock")]
    public virtual List<StockTransaction> StockTransactions { get; set; } = new();

}

public class StockTransaction
{
    public int StockTransactionId { get; set; }

    public int StockId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(StockId))]
    public virtual Stock Stock {get;set;}

    public int? StockFromId { get; set; }
    public virtual Stock? StockFrom { get; set; }

    public int? StockToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Stock? StockTo { get; set; }

 }

